# How do I copy a file multiple times, each with a different filename based on list of values?

Tags: powershell, foreach, iteration, var, copy-item

-New to Powershell/Code-

I need to make multiple copies of "file1.msg", with each filename based on a variable list of values.

I'm using $var to assign a list of filenames that I will copy & paste into Powershell from Excel.

I've tried a few combinations of shown code.

```
$var = "
filename1
filename2
filename3
"
$sourcepath = originalfilelocation.msg
$destination = newfolderforfile\$v.msg

foreach ($v in $var)
{Copy-Item $sourcepath -Destination $destination}
```

I had expected that the CopyItem would work through each of the $v in $var, i.e. first copying the file and renaming it filename1.msg, then iterating through again and copying the file and renaming it filename2.msg.

So far it is copying the file, but only once - and I am struggling with renaming the file based on the values I provide.

Appreciate any guidance/pointers to material. I've tried reading similar questions on the site but still not able to make progress.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you just have a single string object in your variable, so what it looks like in powershell is actually:

```
PS ~/> $destination
newfolderforfile\filename1
filename2
filename3.msg
```

You need to split the list up from a single string object and iterate over it in your `foreach` loop like so:

```
$nameList = @'
filename1
filename2
filename3
'@ -split "`r?`n" # this will turn it into an actual list (array), splitting on newline

$sourcepath = 'originalfilelocation.msg'

foreach ($name in $nameList) {
    $destination = "newfolderforfile\$name.msg"
    Copy-Item -Path $sourcepath -Destination $destination
}
```

---

### Docs for features used:

#### [`about_Foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-5.1)

#### [`about_Quoting_Rules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1#here-strings)

#### [`about_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-5.1)

#### [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-5.1)